# Note-taking and outlining using Vi: On startup, highlight tags and display tags in a preview window

Tags: bash, vim, vi, gvim

I am using `vi` as a note-taking and outlining tool and therefore I thought that this stackexchange site would be appropriate to ask this question. I am constructing the "tags" file by myself. What I would like to do is that when I open my notes or
outline file, vi reads the tags present in this file, highlights them and also displays the tag labels in a vertical preview window. I have no experience
in vim scripting so I would appreciate some help.

Currently I am using a bash script to generate a tag labels file `taglabels` in `$PWD` using `cut` and loading it in a separate vertical window

My script looks like this

```
#! /bin/bash

cut -f1 $PWD/tags > $PWD/taglabels
vi -c ":30vsp $PWD/taglabels" $1
```

As is obvious, the script does not highlight the tags present in the file nor does it show only the tags present in the file. On the contrary it shows
all the tags present in `$PWD/tags`.

I looked into `ctags` and the `taglist` plugin but they seem to be more suited for code than for free-form text.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve on this scenario I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic for [Productivity StackExchange](http://productivity.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This should be closed and reasked on stackoverflow or one of the linux related 'boards.' (Cannnot be merged from beta board)

Comment: I think this is a really cool idea. When you get it working, you should share it! You will likely find much better help on the vim-user mailing list. They field questions like this all of the time. (Sorry for redirecting you a second time.) http://www.vim.org/community.php The best mailing list for this is vim@vim.org.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `vimoutliner`, a `vim` plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3515; I haven't used it myself (don't really use an outliner), but it's easy to install and seems to be to use.